# std::shared_ptr puzzle in function parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, parameters, shared-ptr

I'm using std's smartptrs recently, and I wrote mass code with "shared_ptr", there is some problems in my mind:

1. There have two class:

   ```
   class base{}

   class drived: public base{}
   ```

   and also have two functions like this:

   ```
   void fconst(const shared_ptr<classA>& obj){}

   void f(shared_ptr<classA>& obj){}
   ```

and this function for call test:

```
void test()

{

 std::shared_ptr<drived> obj(std::make_shared<drived>()); 


 f(obj);         // this is error in vc++, because type is not compatibility

 fconst(obj);    // this is ok in vc++

}
```

I understand `f` call is error, but why `fconst` call is ok?

If use `base*` have a benefit: when function receive a `base*` as parameter, the caller can transfer all of base's child as parameter.

and when use `shared_ptr`，is there have similar character?
`fconst` test call's behavior is a reliable standard?

2.
when `shared_ptr` transfer in function parameters, when to these usages:

```
void f(const shaerd_ptr<classA> obj)

void f(const shaerd_ptr<classA>& obj)

void f(shaerd_ptr<classA> obj)

void f(shaerd_ptr<classA>& obj)
```

thank you for your help!

EDIT:
  thank you~, and i also have problems with follow code:

void test()

{

std::shared_ptr obj(std::make_shared());

f(obj);         // this is error in vc++, because type is not compatibility

fconst(obj);    // this is ok in vc++

// continue..

```
std::shared_ptr<base> objBase(std::make_shared<base>()); 

f(objBase);  // this is ok, why? 

fconst(objBase); // this is ok after your answer
```

}

Comment: You can't bind a non-const reference to a temporary, but you can bind a const reference.

Comment: i have update my question, please help again, thank you !~~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example, when calling the const& version, the compiler creates a temporary shared_ptr from your shared_ptr and since temporaries can bind to const&, everything works fine.

Be aware however that this is quite bad, I'd suggest you to either cast your shared_ptr with statis_pointer_cast, or to accept either a reference to base, or a const raw pointer.

```
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class base{};

class drived: public base{};


void fconst(const shared_ptr<base>& obj){}

void f(shared_ptr<base>& obj){}

void f2(shared_ptr<base> a) {}

int main()
{

 std::shared_ptr<drived> obj(std::make_shared<drived>());

 auto h = std::statis_pointer_cast<base>(obj);
 f(h);
 f2(obj);
 fconst(obj);

}
```

Comment: thank you for your detailed description, I know it now!